# Memory errors in Python multiprocessing application

Tags: python, memory, pipe, multiprocess

I am making a script to run multiple instances of threads.

I keep getting errors when running more than 3 concurrent sets of threads, they are mostly to do with the pipes. How can I kill multiple individual processes? Is there a better way to do this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from threading import Thread
import time


alive = {'subAlive': True,  'testAlive': True};


def control_listener(conn, threadAlive): #listens for kill from main
    global alive
    while True:
          data = conn.recv()
           if data == "kill":
               print "Killing"
               alive[threadAlive] = False; #value for kill
               print "testListner alive %s" % threadAlive, alive[threadAlive];
               break

def subprocess(conn, threadNum, threadAlive):
    t = Thread(target=control_listener, args=(conn, threadAlive))
    count = 0
    threadVal = threadNum 
    t.start()
    run = alive['subAlive'];
    while run == True:
          print "Thread %d Run number = %d" % (threadVal, count), alive['subAlive'];
          count = count + 1
          run = alive['subAlive']; 


def testprocess(conn, threadNum, threadAlive):
    t = Thread(target=control_listener, args=(conn, threadAlive))
    count = 0
    threadVal = threadNum 
    t.start()
    run = alive['testAlive'];
    while run == True:
          print "This is a different thread %d Run = %d" % (threadVal, count)
          count = count + 1
          run = alive['testAlive'];

sub_parent, sub_child = Pipe()
test_parent, test_child = Pipe()
runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))


print "Starting threads"

for i in range(threadNum):
    p = Process(target=subprocess, args=(sub_child, i, 'subAlive'))
    p.start()

print "Subprocess started"

for i in range(threadNum): 
    p2 = Process(target=testprocess, args=(test_child, i, 'testAlive'))
    p2.start()

print "Testproccess started"

print "Starting run"

time.sleep(runNum) 

print "Terminating Subprocess run"
for i in range(threadNum):
    sub_parent.send("kill") #sends kill to listener
    print "Testprocess termination alive", alive['subAlive'];

print "Terminating Testprocess run"
for i in range(threadNum):
    test_parent.send("kill") #sends kill to listener
    print "Testprocess termination alive", alive['subAlive'];

p.join()
p2.join()
```

If I run it with more than 2 threads I get random errors like

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:^M
Traceback (most recent call last):^M
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner^M
  self.run()^M
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run^M
   self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)^M
  File "multiprocessDemo.py", line 28, in control_listener^M
   data = conn.recv()^M
 EOFError
```

Or this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):^M
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner^M
self.run()^M
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run^M
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)^M
 File "multiprocessDemo.py", line 28, in control_listener^M
data = conn.recv()^M
MemoryError
```

They occur sporadically when a message would get passed then one of the two threads will stop but the other will keep going.

I want to be able to run this with multiple things going on, say 16 concurrent threads total of one of a few different types.  All I really need this bit to do is stop and start them reliably. I do not need to sync jobs nor do I need complex inter-process communication. Any suggestions? Examples I can look at?